# Turn String into int array bluej

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, bluej

How do you turn a String input into an int array of [][]

Like for example if i have an input of 3a then it should return back to the index of [2][0] and if it have like 5e then it should go to the index of [4][4]

Comment: just curious to know if it's any different in bluej than simply writing `row = Integer.parseInt("" + str.charAt(0)) - 1;` and `col = (str.charAt(1) - 'a');` !

Comment: i don't think is any different then simply writing that
my code right now returns the string like so
`String input;
        
        System.out.print("> ");
        
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        
        return input;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array;

    array = createArray("3a");
    System.out.println(array.length + "," + array[0].length);

    array = createArray("5e");
    System.out.println(array.length + "," + array[0].length);

    array = createArray("9g");
    System.out.println(array.length + "," + array[0].length);
}

private static int[][] createArray(String input) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 1)) - 1;
    int b = input.charAt(1) - 97;
    return new int[a][b];
}
```

This outputs:

```
2,0
4,4
8,6
```

Also make sure to do some method of validation on the input before passing it into `createArray`. A simple regex pattern would do the trick for that: `[0-9][a-z]`.